# Can I use @depends to depend on a test using an @dataProvider?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a testclass in which one test runs multiple times via a `@dataProvider` and another test that `@depends` on the first method. However, when I called `var_dump` on what should be passed to the second test, it gives me a solid `NULL`, which I didn't expect.

In other words: what should this do:

```
<?php 
class DevicesTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider registerDataProvider
     */
    public function testRegister($device, $supposedResult)
    {
        //do a bunch of tests
        return array($device, $supposedResult);
    }

    public function registerDataProvider()
    {
        return array(array("foo", "foo"));
    }

    /**
     * @depends testRegister
     */
    public function testSaveDevicePreferences($deviceArr)
    {
        $this->assertNotEmpty($deviceArr);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Normally `@dataProvider` is used when you want to run a test multiple times with different data sets for each. It exists to save you from writing looping code in the test and to allow different data sets to pass or fail individually.

As I said in my comments, I believe that PHPUnit will use either `@depends` *or* `@dataProvider`, and from your example my guess is that the second wins out. Another possibility is that tests with data providers cannot be used as dependencies because PHPUnit doesn't know which test-plus-dataset to pick.

Since `registerDataProvider` returns a single data set, you could just as easily call it from the test itself. This would allow `@depends` to work in the second test without the `@dataProvider`. Assuming that `testRegister` needs to modify `$device` and/or `$supposedResult`, this should work:

```
class DevicesTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testRegister() {
        list($device, $supposedResult) = $this->registerDataProvider();
        //do a bunch of tests
        //register a device in the DB
        return array($device, $supposedResult);
    }

    public function registerDataProvider() {
        return array("foo", "foo");
    }

    /**
     * @depends testRegister
     */
    public function testSaveDevicePreferences($data) {
        list($device, $supposedResult) = $data;
        // do stuff dependent on testRegister()
        $this->assertEquals($device, $supposedResult);
    }
}
```

If those variables don't need to be modified by the first test, you can simply call `registerDataProvider` from both tests. Note that PHPUnit will not separate a returned array from a dependend upon test into arguments to the dependent test as the data provider mechanism does. This is because it doesn't know that the array being returned is multiple arguments versus a single argument.

Comment: See https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/183#issuecomment-816066 for an explanation on this behavior

Comment: Data from `@dataProvider` comes first, than comes data from `@depends`. That is how it works for me.

Comment: You lose some nice error reporting when you do it this way. Seems appropriate for PHPUnit to either 1) call all dependent tests for each provided data iteration, or 2) forward the return value of the last iteration to the dependent test.

Answer (score 21):

In the current version of PHPUnit (5.4 as of today), it is possible.

According to the [documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers.examples.DependencyAndDataProviderCombo.php):

> When a test receives input from both a @dataProvider method and from one or more tests it @depends on, the arguments from the data provider will come before the ones from depended-upon tests. The arguments from depended-upon tests will be the same for each data set.

This is how it would look practically:

```
<?php

class DataProviderAndDependsCombinationTest extends AbstractUnittest{

    public function dataProviderForSomething()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                'someProvidedValue',
                'someOtherProvidedValue'
            )
        );
    }

    public function testToDependOn()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
        return 'someDependedValue';
    }

     /**
     * @dataProvider dataProviderForSomething
     * @depends testToDependOn
     */
    public function testSomething($someProvidedValue, $someOtherProvidedValue, $someDependedValue)
    {
        $this->assertSame('someProvidedValue', $someProvidedValue);
        $this->assertSame('someOtherProvidedValue', $someOtherProvidedValue);
        $this->assertSame('someDependedValue', $someDependedValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly. This should be accepted for current state.

Comment: Not really what the question was asking about though. OP has `@dataProvider` on the test that is being depended upon, not on the test that is depending on another (as you have here).

Comment: Excellent answer, this definitely should be the accepted answer!

Comment: This answer does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that no, this is not possible. However, by slightly adapting the testclass, I have achieved basically the same result, however, the dependent relation seems to be lost in that if the first test fails, the second happily runs:

```
<?php 
class DevicesTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider registerDataProvider
     */
    public function testRegister($device, $supposedResult)
    {
        //do a bunch of tests
        //register a device in the DB
        return array($device, $supposedResult);
    }

    public function registerDataProvider()
    {
        return array(array("foo", "foo"));
    }

    /**
     * @depends testRegister
     * @dataProvider registerDataProvider
     */
    public function testSaveDevicePreferences($device, $supposedResult)
    {
        // do stuff dependent on testRegister()
        $this->assertEquals($device, $supposedResult);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I'd be curious how this behaves when the data provider method returns an array with more than one array of parameters. The test method should be called once per array of parameters, but test dependencies are designed to depend on a single test method invocation.

Comment: It behaves sort of correctly, however, as I editted in, the second test doesn't get skipped if the first test fails. Furthermore, the second test depends on some things being present in the database, that are put there by the first test. The fact that they are there means that the first test does get run before the second one.

Comment: Tests are run in the order they are declared. PHPUnit doesn't reorder them based on the dependency graph. Since the second test uses the same data provider, it receives its data from that method rather than the test on which it depends. My bet is that PHPUnit looks for `@dataProvider` before `@depends` and thus you could remove the dependency with no effect.